# How do I remove last query from current URL

Tags: php

Let's say my current url is

```
http://domain.com/category/clothing-personal-items/&page=3
```

I used `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get current request uri.

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

The array ouput

```
Array
(
    [path] => /category/clothing-personal-items/&page=3
)
```

**Question :**

How do I retrieve only `/category/clothing-personal-items/` or **remove** any query after `/category/clothing-personal-items/`

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `?` before `page=3`?

Comment: Why do you not begin your query string with the standard "?" character?

Comment: You can simply `explode('?', $url)` and take the first array component.

Comment: The query part of a URL starts with `?` and not `&`.

Comment: @Michael yes.. I use a class routing and it working like that

Comment: @kampit then `explode('&', $url)` instead.

Comment: can't you adjust/alter your parse_url function?

Comment: @Daan Timmer That's a built-in php function.

Comment: @kampit I think there is a bug in your routing class. Query string _must_ start with `?`. In other way, everything after `&` will be treated as a part of URI, not a query. It can lead to some problems, including with SEO.

Comment: @jeroen oops, my bad. I've never used it apparanetly.

Comment: with `?` output `Array ( [0] => /category/clothing-personal-items/&page=3 )` and with `&` `Array ( [0] => /category/clothing-personal-items/ [1] => page=3 )` something wrong the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = explode("?", $url);
$url = array_shift($url);         // explode by ? if it is there
$url = explode("&", $url);
$url = array_shift($url);       // other wise explode by & and return the first item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = $_GET;
array_pop($temp);

$new_query = http_build_query($temp);
```

Then simply add that $new_query string to the current $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Answer (score 0):

```
$parsed = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
if(preg_match('/[^&?]+/',$parsed['path'],$matches))
    $path = $matches[0];
else
    echo "No path found";
```